# Python3 Appending Null bytes with bytearray()

Tags: python-3.x, null, arrays

```
pack = ("test.packet")

pad = (bytearray(b'    ')

with open(pack, 'ab') as file_con_pad_1:
    file_con_pad_1.write(pad)

    print ('4 byte padding added')
```

So how would i go about getting null bytes with this method? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't downvote a question without explaining why.. this site sometimes.

Comment: i look at the documentation for bytearray(), https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html. But it doesnt say anything about null characters.  "The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256". does this mean bytearray cant do null bytes?

Comment: The answer has been clearly stated by myself already. if you would like i could report this necropost.

Comment: I'll edit it. It's quicker to edit it than to debate whether it should be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_pad = ("00000000")

file_pad = binascii.unhexlify(data_pad)

with open(pack, 'ab') as file_con_pad:
    file_con_pad.write(file_pad)
    print ('4 bit padding added')
```

Ended up using this, thanks for all the help and the downvote, such a helpfull community.